# What domain controller is being used for NTAccount.Translate()?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Due to our current infrastructure, a user can end up utilizing different domain controllers after logging into their computer making $env:LOGONSERVER and nltest commands unreliable for determining which domain controller will be used for the translate method.

Is there a way to determine which DC will be used for the translate method?

Comment: I'm curious: why does it matter which domain controller is used? Wouldn't they all give the same answer?

Comment: It all comes down to replication timing issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that `Get-ADDomainController -Discover -Service ADWS -ForceDiscover` seems to do what I needed.

Comment: I don't think that will necessarily tell you which DC `NTAccount.Translate()` will use. It's a good way to _find_ a domain controller that will work with the PowerShell commands (they require ADWS), but otherwise its output probably has nothing to do with the method you're looking at.

Comment: Thank you for commenting, I was hoping a discussion could get started. I believe you are correct in that it doesn't _necessarily_ tell you what DC it will use. However, it forces the discovery process. This means that it won't rely on the cached DC info, which is very important for my environment. When I call this in a script before the translate occurs, it accurately gives the DC that will be used by the translate method.

Comment: interesting, you might be right that it forces the dclocator to update its system cache, but I'm not sure. IIRC the `ActiveDirectory` module is not open source unfortunately, otherwise we could check! You may want to remove `-Service ADWS`. It's unlikely these days that you'd ever be running a DC without it anyway, but more to the point you aren't using the result so might as well let it return any DC.

Comment: Thank you! You are correct it looks like `Get-ADDomainController -ForceDiscover -Discover` works for I need as well.

Comment: Your deleted comment implied that you might use the result in other `ActiveDirectory` module PowerShell commands? If that's true, then you were correct to use `-Service ADWS` because only those DCs will work; of course it's likely you'll never have hit the condition unless you have dangerously old DCs.

Comment: You are correct that the ActiveDirectory module isn't open source. It was one of the first places I went to look. This has been a tricky issue for me to work around. I was quite excited to find something that works in practice.